# Visual Studio 2010 stops implementing changes to executables

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I believe there is a glitch in **Visual Studio 2010** which has haunted me for several years, across numerous different computers irrespective of the Windows version. It happens in both the **express** and **ultimate editions**. I have tried restarting my computer, instead of using shutdown, which did not help.

After coding for a period of time, I will make a change to my C code, for example changing something or perhaps adding a message box. However, this change does not appear in the executable, and I often make numerous changes before I realise this glitch has happened.

I have made a habit of clicking `save all, save, Clean Solution, and then Build`. There are no errors, warnings, and I can check the executable was not in the release folder before compilation.

I routinely lose hours of progress from this bug, as I am mislead into thinking my bug fixes are incorrect, when in actual fact Visual Studio has decided to ignore my changes. It appears to occur when I am rapidly recompiling my executable because I am only making small changes, such as changing strings, and I need then execute the binary to check the changes.

Comment: you are saying after `Clean` and `Build all`, modifications in the source are not compiled?

Comment: Is there a chance you can upgrade to a newer version of VS?

Comment: OT: anyway, maybe it's time to drop a ten year old IDE and switch to Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Whether I change a string, or add a MessageBoxA() at the start of my code's main function it does not appear in the executable. The executable is still doing something I wrote several hours before (creating a temp file in the %TEMP% folder). Visual Studio is just flat out ignoring any code changes.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy Sadly not, I am stuck with Visual Studio 2010. This has been a bug I have encountered so many times over the years.

Comment: The basic edition of Visual Studio is available free of charge.

Comment: @WeatherVane I know, but I will eventually reach a part of this project where having an older version of VisualStudio makes life easier.

Comment: In that case you'll have to find a workaround. Delete all the compiler and linker output files yourself. A batch file makes this easy. If it is *still* running the old version, then it is must be your usage of the tool which is overlooking something.

Comment: sorry, but you are rather imprecise. When you say "The executable is still doing something I wrote several hours before" do you mean "I recompiled but still changes are not reflected in the executable" ? From what you write is sounds as if you expect to modify the code and then automagically have the executable be updated.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Here is a simple example: I made an executable say "Hello World", I deleted it, and cleaned the build using the steps listed in my question. After making changes, for example making it say "Goodbye World" and compiling I am still getting the old popup.

Comment: And what happens if at that point you run the executable from a file manager instead of from the IDE? I don't entirely believe you're not getting in a "version tangle".

Comment: Sounds more like an issue with the filter driver implementation of your anti-malware provider rather than an issue with Visual Studio itself. That, or some ninja changes to your project file, implemented by yourself or a team member, because *"it saves you so much time, lol!"*. To discern between those two, we would need to see a [mcve].

Comment: @WeatherVane I never run it from the IDE, I wait for the newly create .exe file to appear and then I double click it.

Comment: @llnspectable I have had this problem on Windows 7 which IIRC does not have Windows Defender, and I did not have any antivirus installed. I am the only author of this project, nobody else is working on it.

Comment: In that case it isn't compiling the source code that you think it is. Note I have Windows 7 Professional which does have Windows Defender. It is turned off, because I have another AV installed. If you click Start and type *defender* into the search box, it should show up.

Comment: Windows Defender was first released as a download for Windows XP, and later shipped as part of Windows Vista and Windows 7. Regardless, if you aren't running the program from within the IDE there's still the possibility, that you're looking at the wrong directory. Either way, sounds like a [PEBCAK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK).

Comment: " I will eventually reach a part of this project where having an older version of VisualStudio makes life easier" 1) means you're stuck with this version till the end of time 2) I seriously doubt you can't do anything to fix this 3) your life doesn't seems super easy: Windows 7, VS2010, ... :-)

Comment: "_I wait for the newly create .exe file to appear_" Where do you expect this? A) If you delete it manually, is it created when the IDE rebuilds? B) If you command "Clean solution", is it deleted? C) If you change something and rebuild without a manual clean before, does its timestamp change? D) Commonly on Windows there are two "configurations", "debug" and "release". Are you building the one you are looking at? E) Why don't you launch your program from the IDE?

Comment: Everyone: Sometimes I delete the executable in the release folder manually, other times I use clean from within the IDE. The only solution I have found is to add a MessageBox() towards the beginning of my main function which I increment by +1 on each compile, this way I identify straight away when the changes are not incorporated. In regards to Windows Defender, I disabled it in Windows 10 and have no AV installed, and it was not found on my Windows 7 ISO. I have today actually downloaded some malware and used the EICAR antivirus test file to ensure the antivirus is disabled.

Comment: This is a common glitch I experience with Visual Studio. I thought perhaps it was related to my SSD doing wear levelling, however on two different laptops with old HDDs the problem still occurs. I think it is more likely to happen when I am rapidly making changes, as opposed to when each compile is separated by 10-15 minutes of thinking.